# Android MapBox reverse geocoding

Tags: java, android, mapbox, reverse-geocoding, mapbox-android

i am using MapBox for android i am trying to use geocoding mapbox service , here is the code of the reverse geocoding request and response  :

```
        MapboxGeocoding reverseGeocode = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                .accessToken("access token secret code")
                .query(Point.fromLngLat(14.6937, -17.44406))
                .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_ADDRESS)
                .build();
        reverseGeocode.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {

                List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();

                if (results.size() > 0) {

                    // Log the first results Point.
                    Point firstResultPoint = results.get(0).center();
                    for (int i = 0;i<results.size();i++){
                        System.out.println(results.get(i));
                    }

                } else {

                    // No result for your request were found.
                    Log.e( "onResponse:"," No result found");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

it's showing correct reverse geooding results only in europe and america but using any location coordinates in africa it's showing 'results not found' i don't really know from where the error is from my code or the mapbox API dosen't work in africa ?

Comment: Why show your secret access token to the whole world to see? Why don't you use the native and well tested Google's Geocoder class? Do you have specific valid reason not to?

Comment: sorry it's a mistake , well i dont use google maps because it's not free

Comment: Mapbox isn't exactly free either, they only have a free tier.